When should I use "suited" instead of "suitable"?

I want to be a professional volleyball player but I eventually realized that my physique wasn't suitable for it.

Should suitable or suited be used in this context? I don't see the difference between those two here. So when should I use "suited"?

Related (not a duplicate of): “… more suited.” vs “…more suitable.”

Either suitable for it or suited to it is fine. And if you leave off the prepositional phrase, then a bare suitable works fine too.

I really think you need to visit some dictionaries before posting and look at the examples there.

Both can be used, and if there is a shade of difference, I think the difference lies in the results. When a body is used for some activity for which it is not suited, it suffers from such use; whereas when you use your body for something for which it is not suitable, you don't really succeed at that thing.

Children's bodies are not suited to harsh physical labor.
Their roly-poly bodies are not suitable for competitive swimming.

